# Не могу обратиться к другому классу - DrawView

Tags: java, android

Имею два класса - MainActivity и DrawView. В первом - действия, во втором - отрисовка.
При выполнении некоторой функции в первом классе, изменяются поля во втором классе и переменная состояния. А затем вызывается метод invalidate() для запуска новой отрисовки. Но постоянно выдает ошибку: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method или Attemp to write field.

Возможно, что я что-то не так инициализирую или объявляю. Объясните пожалуйста, как не сталкиваться с этой проблемой.

DrawView.java

```
 public class DrawView extends View {

Paint p;


public int x_draw, y_draw;
public int x_point = 0;
public int y_point = 0;
public int draw_state = 0;
public int draw_point = 0;

public DrawView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public DrawView (Context context){
    super (context);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setStrokeWidth(10);
    paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

    Paint paint_dot = new Paint();
    paint_dot.setStrokeWidth(10);
    paint_dot.setColor(Color.RED);

    if (draw_state == 1) {
        canvas.drawRect(x_draw, y_draw, x_draw + 100, y_draw + 100, paint);
    }
    if (draw_point == 1){
        canvas.drawPoint(x_point, y_point, paint_dot);
    }

}
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
...
DrawView drawView;
...
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ...
    drawView = findViewById(R.id.drawViewID);
}
public void startDrawPoint(int x, int y){
    drawView.x_point = x; // ошибка
    drawView.y_point = y; // ошибка
    drawView.draw_point = true; // ошибка
    drawView.invalidate(); // ошибка
}
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_tracking"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="42dp"
        android:text="Отследить"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_marginTop="500dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="120dp"
        android:onClick="btnTrackingOnClick"
        />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/camera_preview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </FrameLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_selectStar"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="42dp"
        android:onClick="btnSelectStarOnClick"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:text="@string/btn_select"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_marginTop="500dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/xS"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="100dp"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_run"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="42dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_marginTop="500dp"
        android:onClick="btnRunOnClick"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:text="@string/btn_start"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_scan"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="42dp"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:onClick="btnScanOnClick"
        android:layout_marginTop="540dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:text="Button"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <com.example.vitalja.stars.DrawView
        android:id="@+id/drawViewID"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:visibility="visible" />



</FrameLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: а в чем смысл сначала создавать `DrawView` программно - `new DrawView(this)`, а потом искать в разметке - `findViewById(R.id.drawViewID)`?

Comment: @ermak0ff, первоначально  drawView = new DrawView(this); - этой строки не было, это я уж пытался различными способами заставить работать это все)

Comment: ну так приведите актуальный код который не работает

Comment: если же он актуален, то приведите файл разметки `activity_main`

Comment: @ermak0ff, добавил разметку. убрал строчк, код актуален.